# Iterate over JSON with ng-repeat (AngularJS)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, json

So I have a JSON file and i want to have 2 select options

- First to select the name (e.g: 'Dev01')
- Second to select one vlan of the first one

So this is inside my controller:

```
    $scope.VLANSelection = {};

    $scope.VLANSelection.selectedOption = null;

    $scope.VLANSelection.availableOptions =  [
            {name: 'Prod01', vlans: [
                    {VlanName: 'ProdVLANHome', id: 0},
                    {VlanName: 'ProdVLANOffice', id: 1}
                ]},
            {name: 'Prod02', vlans: [
                    {VlanName: 'Prod02VLANHome', id: 0},
                    {VlanName: 'Prod02VLANOffice', id: 1}
                ]},
            {name: 'Test01', vlans: [
                    {VlanName: 'Test01VLANHome', id: 0},
                    {VlanName: 'Test01VLANOffice', id: 1}
                ]},
            {name: 'Test02', vlans: [
                    {VlanName: 'Test02VLANHome', id: 0},
                    {VlanName: 'Test02VLANOffice', id: 1}
                ]},
            {name: 'Dev01', vlans: [
                    {VlanName: 'Dev01VLANHome', id: 0},
                    {VlanName: 'Dev01VLANOffice', id: 1}
                ]},
            {name: 'Dev02', vlans: [
                    {VlanName: 'Dev02VLANHome', id: 0},
                    {VlanName: 'Dev01VLANOffice', id: 1}
                ]},
            {name: 'sdf', vlans: [
                    {VlanName: 'Tui01VLANHome', id: 0},
                    {VlanName: 'Tui02VLANOffice', id: 1}
                ]},
            {name: 'dsf', vlans: [
                    {VlanName: 'TuiProdVLANHome', id: 0},
                    {VlanName: 'TuiProdVLANOffice', id: 1}
                ]}
        ];
```

My first selection looks like this:

```
<select class="form-control col-md-9" ng-model="VLANSelection.selectedOption" id="SecurityZoneInput">
                <option ng-repeat="option in VLANSelection.availableOptions" ng-value="{{option}}">{{option.name}}</option>
            </select>
```

And my second selection:

```
<select class="form-control col-md-9"  id="ProdNameInput">
                <option ng-repeat="vlan in VLANSelection.selectedOption track by $index"  ng-value="{{vlan.VlanName}}">{{vlan.VlanName}}</option>
            </select>
```

The First selection looks fine, but inside the second selection I have many empty elements, instead of the 2 Vlan names that should be inside.

So again, if I select 'Prod01' you should see 'ProdVLANHom' and 'ProdVLANOffice' inside the second selection.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
angular.module('mymodule', []);
angular.module('mymodule')
  .controller('myctrl', function($scope) {

    var vm = this;

    vm.selectedOption = null;

    vm.availableOptions = [{
      name: 'Prod01',
      vlans: [{
        VlanName: 'ProdVLANHome',
        id: 0
      }, {
        VlanName: 'ProdVLANOffice',
        id: 1
      }]
    }, {
      name: 'Prod02',
      vlans: [{
        VlanName: 'Prod02VLANHome',
        id: 0
      }, {
        VlanName: 'Prod02VLANOffice',
        id: 1
      }]
    }, {
      name: 'Test01',
      vlans: [{
        VlanName: 'Test01VLANHome',
        id: 0
      }, {
        VlanName: 'Test01VLANOffice',
        id: 1
      }]
    }, {
      name: 'Test02',
      vlans: [{
        VlanName: 'Test02VLANHome',
        id: 0
      }, {
        VlanName: 'Test02VLANOffice',
        id: 1
      }]
    }, {
      name: 'Dev01',
      vlans: [{
        VlanName: 'Dev01VLANHome',
        id: 0
      }, {
        VlanName: 'Dev01VLANOffice',
        id: 1
      }]
    }, {
      name: 'Dev02',
      vlans: [{
        VlanName: 'Dev02VLANHome',
        id: 0
      }, {
        VlanName: 'Dev01VLANOffice',
        id: 1
      }]
    }, {
      name: 'sdf',
      vlans: [{
        VlanName: 'Tui01VLANHome',
        id: 0
      }, {
        VlanName: 'Tui02VLANOffice',
        id: 1
      }]
    }, {
      name: 'dsf',
      vlans: [{
        VlanName: 'TuiProdVLANHome',
        id: 0
      }, {
        VlanName: 'TuiProdVLANOffice',
        id: 1
      }]
    }];

  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="mymodule">
  <div ng-controller="myctrl as ct">
    <div>
      {{ct.selectedOption}}
    </div>
    <select ng-model="ct.selectedOption" ng-options="item  as item.name for item in ct.availableOptions">
      <option ng-repeat="option in ct.availableOptions" ng-value="{{option}}">{{option.name}}</option>
    </select>

    <select ng-model="ct.selectedOption1" ng-options="item as item.VlanName for item in ct.selectedOption.vlans">
      <option ng-repeat="vlan in ct.selectedOption.vlans" ng-value="{{vlan.VlanName}}">{{vlan.VlanName}}</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Looks awesome, thank you! now I only have to integrate it ;)

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you are using an angular directive , no need to use angular expression binding `ng-value="{{option}}"`, Instead you need to give like this `ng-value="option"`

```
<select class="form-control col-md-9" ng-model="VLANSelection.selectedOption" id="SecurityZoneInput" ng-options="option.name for option in VLANSelection.availableOptions" ng-value="option">
    </select>

<select class="form-control col-md-9"  id="ProdNameInput" ng-model="selected" ng-options="vlan.VlanName for vlan in VLANSelection.selectedOption.vlans" ng-value="vlan">
    </select>
```

Comment: Thank you, but still no change.

Comment: can you share a plunker or something ?

Comment: here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/9937/ Just the 'Security Zone' and the 'Name' dropdown is important

Answer (score 0):

For clarification, where is the logic that sets VLanSelection.selectedOption?

I see that you instantiated it and set it to null, which coincidently is why it is showing empty elements.

Try initializing it like this: $scope.VLANSelection.selectedOption = {}; Just the same as you did the Parent.

Comment: I dont any more logic to set the VLanSelection.selectedOption. I tried it to set to {}, no difference. When I try <h1>{{VLANSelection.selectedOption}}</h1> I can see : [object Object],[object Object], which should be fine I guess.. but somehow the second ng-repeat doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Use of `ng-options` might be more clear and appropriate here

```
 <select class="form-control col-md-9" ng-model="VLANSelection.selectedOption" 
    id="SecurityZoneInput" 
ng-options="option as option.name for option in VLANSelection.availableOptions">
 </select>


  <select class="form-control col-md-9" ng-model="test"  id="ProdNameInput" 
ng-options="vlan as vlan.VlanName for vlan in VLANSelection.selectedOption.vlans">
  </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try it using `ng-options`

first select:

```
<select ng-options="option.name for option in VLANSelection.availableOptions" ng-model="VLANSelection.selectedOption" id="SecurityZoneInput">
  </select>
```

and second select

```
<select ng-options="vlan.VlanName for vlan in VLANSelection.selectedOption.vlans track by $index" ng-model="VLANSelection.secondSelect" class="form-control col-md-9" id="ProdNameInput">
```